# Singleton with __new__ returns "Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new_?" using Python 3.8

Tags: python, singleton, metaclass, python-3.8

Trying to change singleton using metaclass of Python 2 to Python 3, `__new__` returns:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file Importing test library 'C:\Users\TestTabs.py' failed: __class__ not set defining 'BrowserDriver' as <class 'BrowserDriver.BrowserDriver'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

CODE:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Newtest')
        if cls._instance is None:
            Singleton._instance = type.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return Singleton._instance
```

This one is called:

```py
class BrowserDriver(metaclass=Singleton)
```

Answer (score 1):

first: *you should not be using a metaclass for having a singleton*

Second: *your "singleton" code is broken*, even if it would work:

By luck it crossed the way of a new mechanism used in class creation, which requires `type.__new__` to receive the "class cell" when creating a new class, and this was detected.

So, the misterious `__class__` cell will exit if any method in your class uses a call to `super()`. Python will create a rathr magic `__class__` variable that will receive a reference to the class that *will* be created, when the class body execution ends. At that point, the `metaclass.__new__` is called. When the call to `metaclass.__new__` returns, the Python runtime expects that the `__class__` magic variable for that class is now "filled in" with a reference to the class itself.

This is for a working class creation - now we come to the bug in your code:
I don't know where you got this "singleton metaclass code" at all, but it is broken: (if it would work), it creates ONE SINGLE CLASS, for all classes using this metaclass - and not, as probably was desired, allow one single-instance of each class using this metaclass. (as the new class body do not have its `__class__` attribute set, you get the error you described under Python 3.8)

In other words: any classes past the first one using this metaclass is simply *ignored*, and not used by the program at all.

The (overkill) idea of using a metaclass to create singleton-enforcing classes is, yes, to allow a single-instance of a class, but the cache for the single instance should be set in the **class** itself, not on the metaclass - or in an attribute in the metaclass that holds one instance for each class created, like a dictionary would. A simple class attribute of the metaclass as featured in this code just makes classes past the first be ignored.

So, to fix that using metaclasses, the cache logic should be in  the metaclass `__call__` method, not in its `__new__` method -

**This is the *expressly* not recommended, but working, metaclass to enforce singletons**:

```py
class SingletonEnforcingmeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        # check "__dict__" entry insead of "hasattr" - allows inheritance
        # and one instance per subclass
        if "_instance" not in cls.__dict__:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls._instance
```

But, as I wrote above, it is overkill to have a metaclass if you just once a singleton - the instantiation mechanism in `__new__` itself is enough for creating a single-instance cache.

But before doing that - on should think: is a "singleton enforcing class really necessary" ? This is Python - the flexible structure and "consenting adults" mindset of the language can have you simply create an instance of your class in the same namespace you created the class itself - and just use that single instance from that point on.

Actually, if your single-instance have the same *name* the class have, one can't even create a new instance by accident, as the class itself will be reachable only indirectly. That is:

**nice thing to do: if you need a singleton, create a singleton, not a 'singleton-enforcing-class**

```py
class BrowserDriver(...):
    # normal code for the class here
    ...

BrowserDriver = BrowserDriver()
```

That is all there is to it. All you have now is a single-instance of
the BrowserDriver class that can be used from any place in your code.

Now, if you *really* need a singleton-enforcing class, one that upon
trying to create any instance beyond the first will silently do not
raise this attempt as an error, and just return the first instance ever created,
then the code you need in then `__new__` method of the class is like the code
you were trying to use as the metaclass´ `__new__`. It records the sinvgle instance in the class itself:

**if really needed: singleton enforcing-class using `__new__`**:

```py
class SingletonBase:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if "_instance" not in cls.__dict__:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return cls._instance
```

And then just inherit your "I must be a singleton" classes from this base.
Note however, that `__init__` will be called on the single-instance at each instantiation attempt - so, these singletons should use  `__new__` (and call `super()` as appropriate,  instead of having an `__init__` method, or have an idempotent `__init__` (i.e. it can be called more than once, but this extra call have no effects)

Comment: Thanks, I could create a single instance, this option could be better.